# jmap -dump is FULL GC be executed?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jmap

I'm trying to create and analyze a heap dump using Java Jmap.
I learned how to do and concept through Google.

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=heapdump.hprof[pid]
```

If the command at the top is executed, does the FULL GC be executed?
If FULL GC is performed, will the application be stopped?

Comment: I see nothing in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html) to suggest either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can heap dump be created for analyzing memory leak without garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393480/can-heap-dump-be-created-for-analyzing-memory-leak-without-garbage-collection)

Comment: " If FULL GC is performed, will the application be stopped?"  - What about if full GC is not performed?  I *think* that the JVM is stopped in both cases, because that is the only efficient way to guarantee a consistent dump ...

Comment: I think it might be sufficient to reach a safepoint which still allows the application to continue executing native code so technically, there could be some things not being stopped.