# Java,How do I find out which class or method USES a lot of memory?

Tags: java, jvm

[image]

This is a one-day memory curve for my Java project.How do I find out which class or method USES a lot of memory?

Comment: here you go - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html

Comment: Thanks, I know about this tool, but my supervisor wants to know which methods are responsible for a large amount of memory usage at a certain time, and which methods generate a large number of objects in the heap.

Comment: For example,Which method produces this String object

Comment: How do you collect the data shown in your graph?  The source is important.

Comment: I used the JavaMelody in this project, but not every project used it, so I wanted to find a generic wayI used the JavaMelody for this project,

Answer (score 3):

You need a tool that can do [JVM allocation profiling](https://www.google.com/search?q=jvm%20allocation%20profiling).

Java Flight Recorder (JFR) can help you with low overhead allocation profiling ([1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks001.html), [2](http://hirt.se/blog/?p=381) — docs for older versions, the UI looks quite different now, but "Allocations" and "TLAB" are still the words used to find stuff). Make sure that allocation profiling [is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056826/java-mission-control-heap-profile) in the settings you use. It's a commercial feature until OpenJDK 11. They say some other tools can do it with low overhead these days too (e.g. [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler)).

If you don't care about your app becoming unusably slow and are on JDK < 11(?), VisualVM used to be able to show you stack traces of allocations. I can't find it in the latest version (1.4.2 as of now), but can find it in JVisualVM shipped with my Oracle JDK 8-something. "Profiler" > check "Settings" > "Memory Settings" > check "Record allocation stack traces". Start profiling, wait, wait, wait, identify the biggest allocations, right-click, "Take Snapshot and Show Allocation Stack Traces". It looks like YourKit [does basically the same](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/allocations.jsp), as well as JProfiler (they call it "allocation recording"). Again: slows down the application a lot, so don't use it in prod.

Answer (score 1):

You have take a heap dump periodically and analyse these with tools like MAT- Memory Analyzer Tool (https://www.eclipse.org/mat/). The tool provides the which Object / Class occupying more memory and from which thread it is created etc.

How to find from which thread particular object is created?

1. In the MAT, click on the Histogram - It will show the list of classes available in the dump. To demonstrate, let me filter out the class `java.lang.String` only

[image]

2. Right click any class name , in the popup-window choose **List Objects ---> with outgoing references**

[image]

3. Above Step list out all the instances of the selected class. Right click any one of the class name and from the pop up choose **Merge Shortest Paths to GC Roots ---> with all references**

[image]

4. After the above step, you can view the From which Thread class particular object is created.

[image]

Comment: _"and from which thread it is created"_ -- the last time I checked, I couldn't find this information in a heap dump, can you maybe give a hint where to look?

Comment: @starikoff , updated the answer for "from which thread it is created".

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate comment and for your effort! I think though you are looking at things slightly wrong: this thread is what has a reference to the object at the time of the dump (this is kinda the definition of a "GC root"). And not all objects will have Thread as the GC root at this point; in fact most probably won't, look into some of your (non-JVM) classes for examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want heap you could run `jmap -histo:live <YOUR PID>` and parse the (fairly terse) output.

[ref](https://medium.com/@jerolba/measuring-actual-memory-consumption-in-java-jmnemohistosyne-5eed2c1edd65)