# How can I find out which classes / variables use all the memory in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, profiling

Really, I would like something similar to [Java,How do I find out which class or method USES a lot of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209349/java-how-do-i-find-out-which-class-or-method-uses-a-lot-of-memory), just for C++

Ideally, something for the stack too.

I'm working on a large codebase and trying to figure out where I could touch to optimize the memory usage of certain runs of the program, or perhaps parallelize it and split it across multiple compute nodes evenly.

I know Valgrind can help with memory LEAKS... but what about memory USAGE?

Comment: You probably need some library or utility to track this. And that may depend on what toolchain you are using. On msvc, I used to use a program called MemoryValidator however the free maintenance ended after a few years of usage and I never renewed.

Comment: You can also ask your [friendly memory allocation library](http://jemalloc.net/jemalloc.3.html) to track allocations based on call stacks.